always encrypted with enclaves randomized DML
We are currently using Always Encrypted with Enclaves in MSSQL 2022. The column encryption option chosen is randomized.
Please refer to the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-enclaves?view=sql-server-ver16
When trying to perform statistical analysis on encrypted column data using Group By, an error occurs stating that the column must use deterministic encryption in order to use Group By.
I'm wondering if I may have misunderstood the explanation in the official documentation. Does anyone have any experience with this issue?
The same issue occurs with Distinct.
I tried switching to deterministic encryption, and the above two DML operations worked fine. However, this contradicts the documentation.

"Is this a bug?" Is that your actual question? If the answer is "Yes" or "No", how does knowing it is(n't) a bug actually help you?

The issue to address is whether I misunderstood the explanation in the official documentation or how to resolve it.

Are all requirements in the linked page supported for your scenario? For example correct compatibility mode, BIN-collations etc

"The issue to address is whether I misunderstood the explanation in the official documentation or how to resolve it" to answer that we need more details; the "bug" could just as likely be in your code or set up; which we have no details of.

Yes, the column is ordered by Chinese_Taiwan_Stroke_BIN2 collation. Tests with equal to, like, and order are all fine.

And it is a char/nchar, not a varchar/nvarchar? Have you followed the documented prerequists?

I have tested with data types char and nvarchar, and the results are the same.
